# Taylor expansion of multi-variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Given that I need to determine the Taylor expansion of a multi-variable function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Is that neccessary that $f$ belongs to the functional space of functions which are partial derivative to the $k$-th order for every combination of order of deriving?

I think that the answer is yes, but something just feels off. And I'm just asking this to verify. Please help me.

Comment: Assuming continuity of those derivatives also might be crucial

Comment: The partials can exists without the function even being continuous, so you need more conditions than just existence of partials.

Comment: You can use the the generalization of the Schwarz theorem for [Symmetry of second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)